# Find individual strings in small array within a larger array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I am stuck with a problem in a project I am doing and was hoping Matlab could save me countless hours.
I have an array containing strings with a corresponding integer in the column next to it (pipe IDs and lengths). I have around 7000 pipe IDs with a corresponding length.

If I have the IDs for say 200 pipes as strings in an array, is it then possible to locate these 200 individual strings within the large array and have MATLAB give me the corresponding pipe length (integer) located in the cell next to the ID string?

I have tried with `ismember` and `strmatch` but I cannot get it working.

**EDIT:**
The large array containing all the data looks like:

```
No.      ID                 Length (m)    
1        0-T103-0-T110      52.327    
2        0-T104-0-1370      30.4    
3        0-T104-0-1410      62.423    
4        0-T105-0-T109      46.611    
...    
7118     0415B-99878        152.242
```

I would then have a smaller array in the same form as above, but instead of 7118 rows I would have for instance 200.

What I have tried so far:

```
a = {'0-T103-0-T110', 52.327; '0-T104-0-1370', 30.4; '0-T104-0-1410', 62.423};
ismember(a(:,1), '0-T104-0-1370');
leng = a{ismember(a(:, 1), '0-T104-0-1370'), 2}
```

This works, but as you can see it is only for locating a single string within a small array.

I have loaded the large arrays as this:

```
[num, text, raw] = xlsread('Pipelength_ALL.xlsx', 'A1:C7115');
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html). Here is an example:

```
%# list of all pipe ID's and their length (100 in this example)
pipes = [cellstr(num2str((1:100)','pip%03d')) num2cell(randi(50,[100 1]))];

%# pipeID's of the query (10 here)
x = randperm(100);
p = cellstr(num2str(x(1:10)','pip%03d'));

%# find matching lengths
[~,loc] = ismember(p, pipes(:,1));
len = cell2mat(pipes(loc,2));
```

A sample of the result:

```
>> [p num2cell(len)]
ans = 
    'pip096'    [14]
    'pip043'    [ 9]
    'pip095'    [27]
    'pip074'    [ 6]
    'pip001'    [ 3]
    'pip065'    [20]
    'pip067'    [ 8]
    'pip060'    [23]
    'pip051'    [27]
    'pip020'    [31]
```

---

### EDIT:

Using the data you posted, the code would be:

```
pipes = {
    '0-T103-0-T110'      52.327
    '0-T104-0-1370'      30.4
    '0-T104-0-1410'      62.423
    '0-T105-0-T109'      46.611
}

p = {
    '0-T104-0-1370'
    '0-T105-0-T109'
}

[~,loc] = ismember(p, pipes(:,1));
[p pipes(loc,2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 
I have not been able to reproduce the above, I get an error message when trying to construct the array 'p'. 
But I think I understand the method used.

Comment: @user1498416: I suspect you have an older MATLAB version where the second argument of `randsample` was not yet introduced. Try replacing that line with: `x = randperm(100); p = cellstr(num2str(x(1:10)','pip%03d'));`

Comment: When I try and use the code 'ismember' I am told the input should be of the type cell arrays of strings. I have tried converting them using 'cellstr' but the data does not appear to change... Also I assume that it is only 'p' that should be this class? 
So if 'p' is that class then 'pipes' should be strings for the IDs and integers for the lenghts or am I missing something?
On MathWorks they are saying that 'ismember' will change could that have something to do with the above and why I can't getting working despite the inputs look very similar to what is described here...

Comment: @Anders: I'm not sure I understood your comment, can you elaborate? `pipes` contain the entire data, while `p` has the IDs of the subset of pipes you want to extract. We are using cell array instead of a regular matrix to store the data because you have mixed data type (strings and numeric)

Comment: When I want to see the class by writing: 'whos pipes' and 'whos p' the class for both of them is 'cell'. 
I have imported the data using [~,~,raw]=xlsread with a column of strings and one with numbers for 'pipes'.
But I keep getting the message:
??? Error using ==> cell.ismember at 28
Input must be cell arrays of strings.

Error in ==> Pipe_enquiry at 14
[~,loc] = ismember(p, pipes(:,1));

I dont know if a screenshot would make it more clear?

Comment: @Anders: yes, type `p` and `pipes` and show the first few lines of each

Comment: Hey I have a link for the screenshots here. They are 'p' and 'pipes' and also the command 'whos' for 'pipes' as well as 'p'. [URL=http://profile.imageshack.us/user/anders_1984]anders_1984[/URL] at 2012-07-06